# Add Text to RichTextBlock-control

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created a RichTextBlock like this

```
RichTextBlock RTB = new RichTextBlock();
```

But I can not find a way to add text and URL's to the RichTextBlock. 
I am thinking, if I need a specific using or something similiar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
    // creat your RichTextBlock  
    RichTextBlock MyRTB = new RichTextBlock();

     // Create a Run of plain text and some bold text.
                Run myRun1 = new Run();
                myRun1.Text = "Some text here";
                myRun1.FontStyle = FontStyle.Oblique;
                myRun1.FontSize = 72;

                Run myRun2 = new Run();
                myRun2.Text = "Other text";
                myRun2.FontSize = 140;
                myRun2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                // Create a paragraph and add the Run and Bold to it.
                Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
                myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun1);
                myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun2);

// add paragraphe to your RichTextBlock  blocks
                MyRTB.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);


// now, add RichTextBlock  to the grid (or any other controler in your page)    
                ParentGrind.Children.Add(MyRTB);
// update layoute
                ParentGrind.UpdateLayout();
```

this work well for me to add and format text dynamically